# Javascript Objects and variable scope

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this to me?

This works:

```
function Pin() { };
function Pi() { };
function User() { };

var PiArray = [];
var PinArray;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    PiArray[i] = new Pi();
    PiArray[i].Name = '';
    PiArray[i].PinArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        PiArray[i].PinArray[j] = new Pin();
        PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Number = j + 2;
        PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseWidth = 0;
        PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseFrenquency = 0;
        PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Dirtybit = false;
    };
}

/* Output is 

[{"Name":"","PinArray":[{"Number":2,"PulseWidth":0,"PulseFrenquency":0,"Dirtybit":false},{"Number":3,"PulseWidth":0,"PulseFrenquency":0,"Dirtybit":false},{"Number":4,"PulseWidth":0,"PulseFrenquency":0,"Dirtybit":false},

etc.

*/
```

But I cannot figure out how to make this into an object, the scope of the variables do not behave as I expect.

this is what an instance of what I tried:

```
function Pin() { };

function Pi() { };

var User = (function () { 

    PiArray = [];

    function User() {
        var PinArray;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            PiArray[i]= new Pi();
            PiArray[i].Name = '';
            PiArray[i].PinArray = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j] = new Pin();
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Number = j + 2;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseWidth = 0;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseFrenquency = 0;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Dirtybit = false;
            };
        }
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(PiArray));
    return User;
})();

new User();
```

and the output is:

```
[ ]
```

I don't understand why?

Comment: ___unclear what you're asking___

Comment: It might help to know what you expect to see, and why.

Comment: Depending on the answer, the environment you're running this in (such as rhino, node, or a browser debugger) may also be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your `console.log(JSON.stringify(PiArray));` shows an empty array in the second case because at the time it runs, you've have not called the function `User()` yet.  The IIFE just defines the function `User()` and then returns it.  It does not actually call it.

Your later code `new User()` does call it, but that's after your `console.log()` has already executed.

Move the `console.log()` to the end of your `User()` function definition (but inside the function) and you will see the expected value.

```
function Pin() { };

function Pi() { };

var User = (function () { 

    PiArray = [];

    function User() {
        var PinArray;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            PiArray[i]= new Pi();
            PiArray[i].Name = '';
            PiArray[i].PinArray = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j] = new Pin();
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Number = j + 2;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseWidth = 0;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].PulseFrenquency = 0;
                PiArray[i].PinArray[j].Dirtybit = false;
            };
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(PiArray));
    }

    return User;
})();

new User();
```

---

FYI, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish with this structure because `PiArray` is only reachable from your constructor.  Once the constructor has been called, no other code can reach it or use it.  Plus all calls to the constructor will modify the same `PiArray`.  `PiArray` in this context works like a class static (as the term is used in other languages).  It's a common variable shared by all instances of the class, but not accessible outside the code for the object itself.

If you had other methods on the `User` object, then they could also access `PiArray` and it might make more sense to have it.

---

You can create an instance that has a different array stored in it like this:

```
var MyObj = function(data) {
    // assign a copy of the passed-in array as instance data
    // You don't have to make a copy - you could just assign in incoming array
    this.data = data.slice(0);
}

var x = new MyObj([1,2,3]);
var y = new MyObj([9,8,7]);
console.log(x.data);    // [1,2,3]
console.log(y.data);    // [9,8,7]
```

Comment: Let's see if I can explain what I am trying to accomplish. I think you answered part of my question. I am trying to instanciate a class in JavaScript. And what I found is just what you said, it looked like a static class. What I want to do is to have instances of a class so the values are different. Can it be done in JavaScript?

Comment: I have an Object with an Array of Objects that has an Array of Objects. And I want to assign different values to different instances. I can do this is C#, but I don't know if I can do this in JavaScript.

Comment: @MarioRosario - I added an example to the end of my answer for creating an object where each instance has a different array in its instance data.